# PHP implicit call of constructor

Tags: php, constructor, implicit-conversion

I wrote a class which is initialize with integer (something like wrapper for int):

```
class MyClass
{
    function __construct ($value)
    {
        // code, code, code
    }
}
```

I also wrote a function which is accepting the object of this class as the parameter:

```
class OtherClass
{
    public function foo (MyClass $obj)
    {
        // code, code, code
    }
}
```

It is possible to simply this call function from:

```
$bar = new OtherClass();
$bar->foo(new MyClass(17));
```

to:

```
$bar = new OtherClass();
$bar->foo(17);
```

?

Comment: Then remove type hinting in the function parameter, or in the function instantiate the MyClass variable P.S: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: It's possible, but it actually makes your code less clear. As it stands now, you do know that your `foo` method uses `MyClass` objects. Without this explicitness, dependency will be hidden.

Comment: I think you're trying to extend class `OtherClass` with `MyClass`. You should read this: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar:

```
class OtherClass
{
    public function foo ($value)
    {
        $obj = new MyClass($value)
        // code, code, code
    }
}
```

But as others mentioned it is less clear...

Comment: That's right, it's truly less clear. I thought it's possible somehow to force PHP to make the implicit conversion from int to MyClass (like in C/C++) without modyfing MyClass and OtherClass.